# Relationship between the coarseness of box topology and the topologies of its coordinate spaces

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I am following the (very good) book "Topology" by Munkres. I am doing the exercise 16.5 at page 92:

> Let $X$ and $X'$ denote a single set in the topologies $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$, respectively; let $Y$ and $Y'$ denote a single set in the topologies $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{U}'$, respectively. Assume these sets are nonempty.
>
> (a) Show that if $\mathcal{T}'\supset\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{U}'\supset\mathcal{U}$, then the product topology on $X'\times Y'$ is finer than the product topology on $X\times Y$.
>
> (b) Does the converse of (a) hold? Justify your answer.

I succeeded in proving (a) without much trouble, but now I am having a hard time seeing if (b) is true or not (i.e. I can't find a suitable counter-example). So I decided to actually prove that it is true and I came up with the following "proof":

Suppose the product topology on $X'\times Y'$ is finer than the one on $X\times Y$. Let $U\in\mathcal{T}$ and $V\in\mathcal{U}$. Then $U\times V$ is a basis element of $X\times Y$ and so $U\times V$ is an open set of $X'\times Y'$. Now, because $\pi_1$ (the projection mapping) is an open map, $\pi_1(U\times V)=U$ is an open set of $X'$. Similarly $V$ is an open set of $Y'$. Hence $\mathcal{T}\subset\mathcal{T}'$ and $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathcal{U}'$.

Does this holds up? Just by the way the question is phrased in the book, I suspect the converse does not actually hold and that I made a mistake somewhere in the preceding paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Answer is correct. The Converse actually holds. You can see another proof of the above question [here](https://www.slader.com/textbook/9780131816299-topology-2nd-edition/92/exercises/5/).